# Image in imageView turned into a question mark in a Swift Xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, storyboard

I'm studying Swift by following Stanford's lecture on iOS development. I'm currently adding an imageView to the storyboard.  I have added an image to the imageView. However, I'm not sure what I have done, but suddenly the image turned into this:

[image]

I'm *not* asking for specific solution to the problem. I just want to know in general, what are some of the reasons that the image added could turn into a question mark.

Comment: Did you set the image of theUIImageView in Storyboard ,then remove the image source in your project or change the name of image in Identity Inspector?

Comment: This means that the image you set in the imageview can't be found in the app resource. It may because you removed the image from the resource or you changed the image name so their names do not match anymore.

Comment: It also happens when you don't specify images for every required size. (1x,2x,3x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting the UIImageView. Then going to Attributes Inspector, and setting the **"Image"** property to a file that XCode doesn't find, will cause the coresponding UIImageView element in the story board to appear with question mark.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

My issue resolved when i just clicked and opened my assets catalog which contained my images

Answer (score 2):

My issue is resolved when i provided all image set in "Assets.xcassets". Images for all required size (1x,2x,3x).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another reason that this can happen is if you've converted to using an Asset Catalog, and removed the images. You will see the blue question mark if you did not remove the ".png" extension from the Image field in Interface Builder. You need to re-point IB to the images in the Asset Catalog.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Xcode should be able to find your images.  You can just click on your `imageViews` in storyboard and this will go away.